# Query on Django list view

Tags: python, django

I have Django list view but I want to put search based on two columns. how to implement this. User would be able to search records based on two columns in same view.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it by `|` and using `Q` like below:

```
from django.db.models import Q

YourModel.objects.filter(Q(column_1__icontains=searched_keyword) | Q(
                column_2__icontains=searched_keyword))
```

I think this can help.